# Page profile picture type large not supported

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I'm trying to load a page's profile picture without authenticating the user. It should be no problem because the "Picture" field of a page doesn't require access token.

So the way I'm trying to show it is using the direct /picture url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/picture?type=large
```

But I'm getting an "unsupported type" error.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/761897607158882/picture?redirect=false
https://graph.facebook.com/761897607158882/picture?redirect=false&type=large
```

If you look at those results, you'll see what I'm talking about. The first shows the picture ok (or the JSON result) and the second shows an unsupported type error:

```
(#100) Unsupported type, 'large'. Supported types: thumbnail, normal, album
```

What do you think is happening? What do you think is the best approach to get the current profile picture of a fanpage?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternate formulation that will return a 200px high image.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/761897607158882/picture?redirect=false&width=200&height=200
```

Comment: I ended up using this approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

why don't try `https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/picture?type=normal` . error clearly says large not supported but type normal,thumbnail,album is.

Comment: Yeah I think it's the best approach for now. However I think it's a weird thing on facebook that some pages has the type large available and others don't.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You might be sending a very large file, or the server does not support the extension of the file.